# Is SwipeDelegate working for horizontal orientation?

Tags: qt, qml

With default vertical orientation everything work as intended. But for horizontal orientation swipe direction not changed and I can't find swipe.up, swipe.down or something like this. Any solution or workaround for this?

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Hello World"
    width: 640
    height: 480

    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal

        model: 20
        delegate: SwipeDelegate {
            id: swipeDelegate
            text: modelData
            width: 50
            height: root.height

            swipe.behind: Label {
                id: deleteLabel
                text: qsTr("Delete")
                color: "white"
                verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
                padding: 12
                height: parent.height
                anchors.right: parent.right

                background: Rectangle {
                    color: deleteLabel.SwipeDelegate.pressed ? Qt.darker("tomato", 1.1) : "tomato"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to separate between swiping the delegate and scrolling the ListView?

Comment: Scrolling will be horizontal, swiping vertical. It's obvious, I think.